# Docker inside docker: file missing

Tags: docker, dockerpy

I am launching docker inside another docker container and I'm trying to make files visible inside "deepest" container.

My first container is build on `python:3.8-slim` image, entrypoint is `["python"]` and is called `test-client`.

I launch it as `docker run --rm -it -v /home/.../inputs:/inputs -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --network ... test-client start_client.py ...`.

Now inner container.
Inside `start_client.py` I run it with `docker==5.0.3` library.

```
def check_docker():
    import time
    inputs = Mount('/inputs', 'inputs')
    client = docker.from_env()
    client.images.pull('apline')
    time.sleep(30) # I will explain this later
    output = client.containers.run(
        'apline', 'ls inputs -al',
         mounts=[inputs]
    ).decode('utf-8')
    for line in output.split('\n'):
        print(line)
```

So. I used `time.sleep` to have time to dive into first container and check if needed file is presed. Yes it is, my file is inside first container. But output of deepest container sees no files inside `inputs` directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I might be wrong. But it seems that when you use `docker.from_env()`, it's taking your host's path? Maybe you can check by doing `ls /inputs` on your host. If it exists, then the inner docker container is mounting your host's directory and not the `/inputs` from your first container

Comment: @marmikshah it doesn't exist.

Comment: @marmikshah but your idea actually lead me to understand what was I missing. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly mount a directory from one container to another.  In the `mounts` option you show (and in `docker run -v` and Compose `volumes:`) the host path is always a path on the system where the Docker daemon is running.  If you're bind-mounting the host's Docker socket, these paths will be paths on the host; if `$DOCKER_HOST` points into a VM or at a remote machine, the paths will be paths on that system and not your local one.

But, in your specific example, the directory you're trying to remount is already a mount itself.  If you mount the same host location into both containers, then you'll be able to see the files.  I'd suggest specifying this in an environment variable

```py
inputs = Mount('/inputs', os.getenv('INPUT_SOURCE', 'input'))
```

and when you run the container, pass that directory in as a variable

```sh
INPUT_SOURCE="$PWD/inputs"
docker run --rm -it \
  -e INPUT_SOURCE \
  -v "$INPUT_SOURCE:/inputs" \
  --network ... \
  test-client \
  start_client.py ...
```

If you use a bare string `input` in the [Mount](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#docker.types.Mount) object as you've done, it will mount (and automatically create) a named volume.  You can use your container to inspect this

```sh
docker run --rm -v inputs:/inputs test-client \
  -e 'print(os.listdir("/inputs"))'
```

(you can use a simpler shell syntax if you remove the `ENTRYPOINT ["python"]` line from your Dockerfile).